# Link Problem!Anyone helps?

Tags: visualforce

I have app with links who works on my instance na24. when i deploy app,links dont works. I get message not enough permissions.i write code like on email attached. Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

[image]

Comment: can you pls add a screenshot of error message?

Comment: yes,i add picture now.

Comment: Can you please check the user have access to object you are trying to access using url?

Comment: I have all access to this object.

Comment: if you have all the access. So what ever you are using `/a07` or something in link is this  related to any object in product or not?

Comment: is related to custom tab in my project.

Comment: looks like this is only access issue nothing else.

Comment: do you think in access issue in custom profile for that tab?

Comment: not tab. Access issue with object. Current user doesn't have access  to your custom object. or can you just paste your url of above issue?

Comment: I add picture of permission for that object as you can see,its full permission.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'm just going to write it here. It's probably due to the security issues. I've had the same probles with vf pages, apex classes and sites. In sites I've had to go through "public access settings" in apex classes it was the "security" link and in the user section I've had to specify the user type. Have a little play around and see if that fices the issue. [image: Si]

[image: Apex classes]

[image: User Section]

Each individual thing has it's own security preferences. go to what you working with right now and have a look. I hope this helps